# How can I install Java SDK on Windows 7 without messing up the system?

Tags: windows-7, java

I've installed Java SE Development Kit 1.6.0_31 32bit on Windows 7 64bit system, but this installation messed up my system, e.g. when I start Google Chrome I get error

> Your preferences can not be read

Visual Studio 2010 after launching shows error that

> The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created

The shortcut to the Downloads folder in Windows Explorer no longer works. 
BTW this is pretty clean install, on other occasions after Java installation I had
problems like this
http://forums.techguy.org/windows-vista/808717-solved-c-windows-system32-config.html

Is there a way to install Java SDK without messing up Windows 7? Or maybe this mess can be cleaned up after installation of Java, but how?

Comment: I restored my system, now I want to know how to install Java without messing up my system again.

Comment: Your question didn't state that you restored it – and you reported the error messages in the present tense, which is why I guessed they were still there, sorry.

Comment: java should NOT have done this. I dont think this is Java's fault. It sounds like you killed your %appdata% folder

Comment: I have this problem always after installing Java, be it JRE or Java SDK, version 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: You installed it as administrator.. right?

Comment: Yes, you can't install java as a ordinary user.

Answer (score 1):

Use System Restore to restore your system to a date prior to your installation of Java.

Comment: I know that, I want help on clean installation of Java.

Comment: Just install the latest 64bit version. I have it installed properly on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Comment: Which version have you installed? I had the same problem with latest version of Java 1.7 64 bit.

Comment: I have 1.6.32 64bit. I have no problems with either Chrome or VS2010. And by the way, both do not rely (and in the case of VS even use) on Java, so I don't understand what exactly caused your issues.

Comment: Issues are caused by piece of crap Java installer which messes up Windows 7 configuration, this is the only program that I have such problems.

Comment: You won't get any argument from me there - the Java installer is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. I had to change Region and Language settings to **English (US)**. Previously I had mixed English and metric settings. BTW if you are going to use Adroid SDK, you have to install 32bit Java - stupid Android installer won't find 64bit Java.